# GEdit 'Session Saver'

Tags: ubuntu, session, gedit

I use '[session saver](http://live.gnome.org/GeditPlugins)' with GEdit on Ubuntu 11.10. I would like to know where GEdit stores them so that I can automatically back it using DropBox.

> Session Saver: Allow to bookmark working sessions in order to get them back for further use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The details are saved as a XML file in `~/.config/gedit/`. The file concerned is saved with the name `saved-sessions.xml`.

I can't tell if it is useful to sync this file using DropBox because all it ever saves in the file is the exact file path. But, it is a different story if you are storing the same file in the same path across different machines.